# R package with Rcpp builds, but when calling function: Error in .Call

Tags: rcpp, r-package

I am trying to add C++ code to my R package. My package code is on Github: https://github.com/wadpac/GGIR. I have been reading the Writting R Extensions documentation, but no succes so far:

```
install.packages('Rcpp')
Rcpp.package.skeleton("GGIR", cpp_files = c("src/numUnpack.cpp","src/resample.cpp")
package_native_routine_registration_skeleton(".")
R CMD build .
R CMD check --no-manual ../GGIR_1.5-4.tar.gz
Status: OK
install.packages("~/GGIR/GGIR_1.5-4.tar.gz",dependencies=TRUE
* DONE (GGIR)
```

Untill here, everything seems to have gone well because the package builds and I have a source file I can install. However, when I try to use the R function that relies on the c++ code I get:

`P = g.cwaread("/media/windows-share/testdata/testfile.cwa",start=1,end=10)
Error in .Call("GGIR_numUnpack", PACKAGE = "GGIR", pack) : 
  "GGIR_numUnpack" not available for .Call() for package "GGIR"`

The C++ code works on my machine when using  for example Rcpp::sourceCpp('src/numUnpack.cpp') directly.

I elaborate on my investigations so far at: https://github.com/wadpac/GGIR/issues/6

Session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=nl_NL.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=nl_NL.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=nl_NL.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=nl_NL.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] GGIR_1.5-4   Rcpp_0.12.10

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0    tools_3.4.0       data.table_1.10.4
```

Comment: In `NAMESPACE`, what happens if you drop `.fixes = "C_"`? e.g. just use: `useDynLib(GGIR, .registration=TRUE)`

Comment: Also, can you add data that goes with this to make it reproducible?

Comment: Thanks for having a look. Example data is [here](http://www.axivity.com/files/resources/longitudinal_data.zip) (zipped 53MB, unzipped 251MB). Removing `.fixes = "C_"` does not change the error.

Comment: It may be a little much to expect us to muck with 53mb / 251mb unpacked.  Maybe you could look at the 1000+ existing CRAN packages, or create one with `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`, or via its within-RStudio equivalent, or ...

Comment: I think that fixed it, thanks for your encouragement to look one more time at other packages even though I had already been looking at them for hours. The mistake was in my init.c file where I added variable names afer the extern statements. To prevent people like me ending here in the future: Having a Hello world example with routine registraction included would be good, so with these two commands combined in one blog/example. Rcpp.package.skeleton() and
package_native_routine_registration_skeleton("."). thanks Dirk + @coatless

Comment: With hindsight the Writing R Extensions [section](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Converting-a-package-to-use-registration) that gives the registration example did confuse me. It gives the example: spline_basis(SEXP knots, SEXP order, SEXP xvals, SEXP derivs) while in my init.c code equivalent that would be: GGIR_resample(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP), so without variable names. As c++ newbie this was not obvious to me.

Comment: Dang. I added `src/init.c` for the Rcpp Modules and Rcpp Class examples and forgot to do it for `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`.  Will rectify.

Comment: Now committed, and likely merged to master soon.  Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this, and the above comments didn't seem to help much.  What worked was making sure the `useDynLib(<package>)` statement is added to the NAMESPACE file. (Note that `<package>` should be the name of your package.)

Of course, if you are using *roxygen2*, then you can't edit the NAMESPACE file by hand.  So what you do is add the `useDynLib` statement to the *usethis* namespace file.  Like this:

```
## usethis namespace: start
#' @importFrom Rcpp sourceCpp
#' @useDynLib <package>
## usethis namespace: end
NULL
```

Then regenerate your documentation and it will show up in the NAMESPACE like this:

```
import(readr)
import(readxl)
import(tibble)
import(tools)
importFrom(Rcpp,sourceCpp)
useDynLib(<package>)
```

If the `useDynLib(<package>)` statement is not added to the NAMESPACE, your code won't be able to find your *Rcpp* functions.